# Conditional Computed Columns in SQL Server Views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

I am trying to create a SQL Server 2008 view from an existing table `Students` with the following query:

```
SELECT Std_ID, 
       Name, 
       Sub1, 
       Sub2, 
       IIf ((Sub1 + Sub2)>160, 'A',
       IIf ((Sub1 + Sub2)>100, 'B','C')) AS Legend 
FROM  dbo.Student
```

It gives me an error mentioned below.

> Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.

I am expecting the view to have the calculated column `Legend`. The query executes perfectly in Query Designer, but the view fails to create. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

IIF is a new feature in SQL Server 2012 (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2570/new-logical-functions-in-sql-server-2012-iif-and-choose/). You can't design in 2012 and expect it to work in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
   SELECT 
     Std_ID, 
     Name, 
     Sub1, 
     Sub2, 
     Legend = 
           case 
             when Sub1 + Sub2 > 160 then 'A'
             when Sub1 + Sub2 > 100 then 'B'
             else 'C'
           end
    FROM  dbo.Student
```